# Como puedo compilar todo archivo TypeScript hacia una carpeta diferente

Tags: javascript, typescript

Tengo una carpeta principal en donde tengo la carpeta "TS" y "JS", entonces lo que quiero es que todo archivo ts dentro de la carpeta"TS" se transpile hacia la carpeta js.

Yo actualmente estaba ejecutando a traves de un emulador de control de comandos, en el directorio TS que todo archivo extension ts se transpilara, pero el problema es que el archivo queda junto en la misma carpeta.

Esto es nuevo para mi, por si existen errores obvios mil disculpas

```
Javier'Andres@Equipo-Javier /cygdrive/c/Users/Javier'Andres/Desktop/Curso JS/POO-TypeScript/ts
$ tsc -w *.ts
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pude lograr que queria creando un archivo tsconfig.json en la raiz del proyecto

con los siguentes parametros:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {

    "target": "es5",   
    "watch": true,     // cada ves que se ejecute un archivo extension TS se va ejecutar el compilador                  
    "outDir": "./POO-TypeScript/js",  //establezco el directorio en donde se van a guardar los archivos Js                
    "rootDir":"./POO-TypeScript/ts"  //establezco el directorio en donde se van a encontrar los archivos TS a compilar                 

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En el archivo tsconfig.json:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "js"
    ...
```